# This is my code for a simple java game. How can I display the letters already guessed so they cannot guess the same letter twice

Tags: java

```
import java.util;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanJava
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)    //creates an array
   {
    String input;
    boolean NotFullMan = true;
    char guessedLetter = ' ';                          
    Scanner hm = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the hangman word");
    input = hm.nextLine();  

    //Convert String to CharArray 

    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();            
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(input.length());             

    int totalCorrect = 0;    

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)         
      buffer.append('_');

    while (NotFullMan)
     {
     System.out.println("Enter a letter");
     guessedLetter = hm.nextLine().charAt(0);     
     int correct = 0;

     for ( int i=0; i < charArray.length; i++)
       {                //Checks each letter
        if(guessedLetter == charArray[i] && buffer.charAt(i) == '_')
         { 
         correct++;
         totalCorrect++;      //totalCorrect so it can keep track
         buffer.setCharAt(i, guessedLetter);
         }
      }
      System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct!");
      System.out.println(buffer.toString());


      if (totalCorrect == input.length())   //ends when totalCorrect is equal to the number of characters in word
         return;

    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: First, reformat the code so that it is properly readable on SO.  Make sure it compiles.  (It definitely doesn't at the moment: you have your /* ... */ comments inverted, for one.)  Remove any extraneous parts (e.g. the commented out block).  Then you'll have a much better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You store every guessed letter in `char guessedLetter`.
Every time you do that, store that letter inside a `Collection`, like an `ArrayList` for instance:

```
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
chars.add(guessedLetter);
```

Then, when you want to check if the user already guessed a letter you check:

```
if(chars.contains(guessedLetter)){
    // already guessed
    // possibly re-ask to guess a different letter
    // recommended to do this in a while loop until correct guess is made
}
else{
    // never guessed this letter -> continue normally
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: @John if my answer solved your question please consider accepting it, by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Idos's answer, when you go to display the list you can either write code that iterates over the characters to format them or you can just build a string using library methods.  Below are some example output strings, three of which are comma delimited:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : chars)
{
  sb.append(c);
  sb.append(',');
}
sb.deleteCharAt(string1.length() - 1);
String string1 = sb.toString();
String string2 = new String(chars);

//These two only work in Java 8
String string3 = String.join(',', chars);
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(',');
for (char c : chars)
{
  sj.add(c);
  sj.add(',');
}
String string4 = sj.toString();
```